# Count non zero entry in row in R

Tags: r

I have following kind of data:

```
   mode1 mode2 mode3
1     8     1     0
2     0     0     0
3     6     5     4
4     1     2     3
5     1     1     1
```

Data using `dput`:

```
structure(list(mode1 = c(8L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 1L), mode2 = c(1L, 0L, 
5L, 2L, 1L), mode3 = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names 
= c(NA,-5L))
```

I need to count number of non-zero entry in R. The problem I am facing is: all columns are in `factor` so if I convert to `numeric` then data values are changed.

Expected output:

```
   mode1 mode2 mode3 Count
1     8     1     0   2
2     0     0     0   0
3     6     5     4   3
4     1     2     3   3
5     1     1     1   3
```

Basically, `count` is a new column which counts number of non zero values row-wise. I tried `length(xml_df[1,]!=0)` but couldn't able to find answer.

Comment: @A.Suliman: Thanks for the answer.  Worked!

Comment: This is a working too: `xml_df[xml_df[1,]!=0,]`

Comment: In a case of multiple rows you do: `xml_df$count <- rowSums(xml_df!=0)` as shown 21 minutes before this comment by Suliman.

Comment: @AndreElrico: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're most welcome. `rowSums` is a super cool function. Use it where ever you can.

Comment: @A.Suliman: Can you please add your comment as an answer? Sorry for the late response!

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan thanks for your kind suggestion, please check my update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In base R

```
df$count <- rowSums(df!=0)
  mode1 mode2 mode3 count
1     8     1     0     2
2     0     0     0     0
3     6     5     4     3
4     1     2     3     3
5     1     1     1     3
```

Using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(count=rowSums(.!=0))
#For specific columns we can use
df %>% mutate(count=rowSums(.[1:3]!=0))
#OR
df %>% mutate(count=rowSums(select(.,starts_with("mode"))!=0))
```